# How to create index in firebird for improvement of select query

Tags: sql, indexing, firebird

I am newbie in using firebird. I have 3 tables.

for **T_TABLE1** the structure is shown below:

[image]

for **T_TABLE2** the structure is shown below:

[image]

and for **T_TABLE3** the structure is like this:

[image]

the primary key is the **ID** from **T_TABLE1** to **TBL1_ID** in **T_TABEL2** and **TBL1_ID** in **T_TABLE3**. How can I select data join with that 3 tables and I want to use **index** for best select query but I don't know how to create index because I am newbie in using firebird and I want to learn more in using firebird. Hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys from `T_TABEL2.TBL1_ID` to `T_TABLE1.ID` (and same for `T_TABLE3.TBL1_ID`)? If so there are no additional relevant indexes to add. And for documentation, see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for creating an index is documented in The Firebird 2.5 Language Reference, [CREATE INDEX](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-idx-create), it also contains additional information.

The syntax for creating an index is:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE] [ASC[ENDING] | [DESC[ENDING]] INDEX indexname
   ON tablename
   { (<col> [, <col> ...]) | COMPUTED BY (expression) }

<col>  ::=  a column not of type ARRAY, BLOB or COMPUTED BY
```

So for creating an (ascending) index on `T_TABEL2.TBL1_ID` you would do:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tabel2_tbl1_id ON T_TABEL2 (TBL1_ID)
```

But as I commented earlier today that is not necessary if there is a foreign key on this column, as foreign keys in Firebird automatically get an index (the same applies to primary keys).

It is not clear from your question if you have foreign keys, but I'd advise you to create them instead of an index: it gives you the index and on top of that enforces that the value of `TBL1_ID` actually exists in `T_TABLE1`.

Just keep in mind that creating an index does not automatically improve performance. The optimizer for example might decide that using an index is not worth the effort (or that a specific index is not relevant for the query).

Comment: Okay sir. Thanks! I do not have a foreign key in my tables. I will create foreign key. Sir, If I already have a foreign key, how can I use SELECT query with INDEX? Thanks sir. I really dont have any idea in using INDEX. But, I start reading manuals and tutorials, but others are not yet clear. I read about using 'PLAN'. THANKS!

Comment: Firebird itself will automatically select an index if it is relevant (and expected to improve performance). You can specify an explicit plan if you think Firebird is wrong, but that is advanced stuff that you can better ignore if you are new to it.