# How to use index in firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, indexing

I have here query in firebird, I am newbie in using firebird and index. I want to optimize my query by using index. But i don't know how, here is my query:

```sql
SELECT  
      a.TESTER,  
      a.LOT_ID,  
      /* DATEDIFF (SECOND FROM START_LOG_TIME TO ENDLOGTIME) AS ELAPSED_TIME */  
      b.TEST_DESC,  
      COUNT(TEST_DESC) AS TOTAL_DESC,  
      MIN(MEASUREMENT) AS MIN_MEASUREMENT,  
      AVG(MEASUREMENT) AS TOTAL_MEASUREMENT,  
      MAX(MEASUREMENT) AS MAX_MEASUREMENT,  
      AVG(LL) AS LL,  
      AVG(UL) AS UL,  
      SUM(IIF(MEASUREMENT<LL,1,0)) AS RESULT  

FROM T_TABLE1 a  
INNER JOIN T_TABLE2 b  
      ON a.ID = b.TBL1_ID  
      AND a.TESTER = b.TESTER  
      AND a.LOT_ID = b.LOT_ID  
WHERE b.GRP = 'Contact'  
GROUP BY  
      a.TESTER,  
      a.LOT_ID,  
      b.TEST_DESC
```

and for **T_TABLE2**, I tried to create index named **TEST_DESC_IDX**. I created index for TEST_DESC field.

THANKS for the help!!

Comment: Yes, I already created index, but this time. I dont know how to use index together with INNER JOIN and GROUP BY. I got some error when I put PLAN in my query.

Comment: You usually don't force the engine to use a particular index, but let the optimizer choose the best plan available at the time. In other words, the engine will automatically use the best available indexes. You use the PLAN clause only in very rare cases.

Answer (score 1):

My comment on [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19232536/466862) is an answer to this one:

Firebird itself will automatically select an index if it is relevant (and expected to improve performance). You can specify an explicit plan if you think Firebird is wrong, but that is advanced stuff that you can better ignore if you are new to it.